# TableViewCell not updating

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a TableView Controller with custom cells that I want reload with new data whenever the table view is loaded.

The problem I'm having is the data is reloading properly but the cell labels are not.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> JobTableViewCell{


    jobSelect = Int(indexPath.row)



    var cell:  JobTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("JobTableViewCell") as JobTableViewCell



    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0{cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
    else {cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()}


    var job = arrayOfJobs[indexPath.row]
    var totalHours = job.monHours + job.tueHours + job.wedHours + job.thuHours + job.friHours + job.satHours + job.sunHours

    cell.setCell(job.jobName, income: job.income, commute: job.commute, jobHours: totalHours)

    return cell
}
```

Here is the custom cell -

```
import UIKit





class JobTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var jobTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var income: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var commute: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var jobHours: UILabel!



override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)



    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

 func setCell(jobTitle: String, income: Int, commute: Int, jobHours: Int){





    self.jobTitle.text = String(arrayOfJobs[jobSelect
        ].jobName)
    self.income.text = String("Income: $\(arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].income) a month")
    self.commute.text = String("Commute: \(arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].commute) hours away from home")
    self.jobHours.text = String("Available hours:\(arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].monHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].tueHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].wedHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].thuHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].friHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].satHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].sunHours) hours a week")




 }
}
```

I also have a second view controller set up that appears when a cell is selected -

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



    jobSelect = Int(indexPath.row)


    var JobSelector:  jobSubView = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("jobSubView") as jobSubView



    self.presentViewController(JobSelector, animated: true, completion: nil)



    self.rowSelection = Int(indexPath.row)


}
```

Here is the sub view -

```
import UIKit

class jobSubView: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var jobTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var income: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var commute: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var jobHours: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var qualifications: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var jobDescription: UITextView!

@IBOutlet var goBackButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var appluButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func applyButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.jobTitle.text = String(arrayOfJobs[jobSelect
        ].jobName)
    self.income.text = String("Income: $\(arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].income) a month")
    self.commute.text = String("Commute: \(arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].commute) hours away from home")
    self.jobHours.text = String("Available hours: \(arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].monHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].tueHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].wedHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].thuHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].friHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].satHours + arrayOfJobs[jobSelect].sunHours) hours a week")


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

The labels on the cell and the subviews are drawing from the same data.  When the tableview loads the first time both the cells and the sub view display correctly.

The subview loads with the correct data when a cell is selected, but when I return to the tableview the cell labels should update, but they are not.  But the sub view labels are.

Any ideas?

Comment: this might help 

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787480/refresh-table-view

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583325/ios-reload-table-view-not-working

Comment: self.tableView.reloadData() is not working.

Comment: Your override for cellForRowAtIndexPath returns a JobTableViewCell. Are you sure that is a valid override for cellForRowAtIndexPath which is defined as returning a UITableViewCell?

Comment: using override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  vs override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> JobTableViewCell doesn't seem to make a difference.  The cells load fine the first time I bring up the TableViewController.  It is when I reload it they do not reload with the new data.  The subView does however.  It's driving me nuts!

Comment: so I just figured out that they ARE updating... but only after I scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured this out. You have to do self.tableView.reloadData() in viewWillAppear  instead of viewDidLoad.